# What do I implement to handle popup, and dialog windows ina custom X11 window manager?

Tags: x11, xlib

I'm currently developing a simple window manager in C++ using Xlib. I've implemented a basic master/stack tiling algorithm, and what I've noticed is that whenever I open a "complex" app (such as midori, or even thunar) with a lot of "popup" dialogs that are a separate window (such as the mini window that opens when you hover on a disk in thunar), they also get inevitable tiled.

While I've tried reading the EWMH and ICCCM docs, I'm not exactly sure which rules and properties I should implement first, to get these types of apps working.

So kindly tell me the bare minimum I should I implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep an eye out for these three important attributes and properties:

1. [Override Redirect Flag](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/attributes/override-redirect.html)
2. [WM_TRANSIENT_FOR Property](https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-4.html#WM_TRANSIENT_FOR)
3. [_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/latest/ar01s05.html#idm45584883008224)

For example, the `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DIALOG` section states:

> If _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE is not set, then managed windows with WM_TRANSIENT_FOR set MUST be taken as this type. Override-redirect windows with WM_TRANSIENT_FOR, but without _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE must be taken as _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL.

**More Infos:**

- [Inter-Client Communication Conventions Manual](https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/)
- [Extended Window Manager Hints](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/latest/)